# Why does my player_turns() not increment by 1?

Tags: python

I am working on a 2-player battleships game written in python. My player_turns() makes it so that it alternates between player 1 and player 2. However when you play it stays only on player 1, why is this the case?

Also, I've noticed that if you find the ship's location and start a new game, the ship does not find a new location and keeps the same coordinates as it had last game. How can I make it so that the coordinates change every game?

```
from random import randint

game_board = []
player_one = {
    "name": "Player 1",
    "wins": 0,
    "lose": 0
}
player_two = {
    "name": "Player 2",
    "wins": 0,
    "lose": 0
}

# Building our 5 x 5 board
def build_game_board(board):
    for item in range(5):
        board.append(["O"] * 5)

def show_board(board):
    print("Find and sink the ship!")
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

# Defining ships locations
def load_game(board):
    print("WELCOME TO BATTLESHIP!")
    print("START")
    del board[:]
    build_game_board(board)
    show_board(board)
    ship_col = randint(1, len(board))
    ship_row = randint(1, len(board[0]))
    return {
        'ship_col': ship_col,
        'ship_row': ship_row,
    }

ship_points = load_game(game_board)

# Players will alternate turns.
def player_turns():
    total_turns = 0
    if total_turns % 2 == 0:
        return player_one
        total_turns += 1

    else:
        return player_two

# Allows new game to start
def play_again():
    answer = input("Would you like to play again? ")
    if answer == "yes" or answer == "y":
        total_turns = 0
        ship_points = load_game(game_board)

    else:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        exit()

# What will be done with players guesses
def input_check(ship_row, ship_col, player, board):
    guess_col = 0
    guess_row = 0
    while True:
        try:
            guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:")) - 1
            guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:")) - 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a number only: ")
            continue
        else:
            break
    match = guess_row == ship_row - 1 and guess_col == ship_col - 1
    not_on_game_board = (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4)

    if match:
        player["wins"] += 1
        print("Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        play_again()

    elif not match:
        if not_on_game_board:
            print("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")

        elif board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X":
            print("You guessed that one already.")

        else:
            print("You missed my battleship!")
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
        show_board(game_board)

    else:
        return 0


def main():
    begin = input('Type \'start\' to begin: ')
    while (begin != str('start')):
        begin = input('Type \'start\' to begin: ')
    for games in range(3):
        for turns in range(6):

            if player_turns() == player_one:
                print("Player One")
                input_check(
                    ship_points['ship_row'],
                    ship_points['ship_col'],
                    player_one, game_board
                )

            elif player_turns() == player_two:
                print("Player Two")
                input_check(
                    ship_points['ship_row'],
                    ship_points['ship_col'],
                    player_two, game_board
                )

            if turns == 6:
                print("The game is a draw")
                play_again()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: every time you call `player_turns` you reset `total_turns` to 0.

Comment: When I put total_turns = 0 as a global variable I get the following error  `local variable 'total_turns' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: You really need to read about scoping rules in Python : what are local / global variables, how to share variables between functions and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is there anyway I can initialise my variable total_turns so that It was not keep resetting itself?

Comment: after return the block is stopped

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `return` statement after incrementing `total_turns`.

Once the return statement is executed, the function is exited.

Comment: Does not work. I have put total_turns = 0 at the top of my program and done as you said. I still get the following error `local variable 'total_turns' referenced before assignment`.